# Why do I get "FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user" when trying to log into my postgres DB?

Tags: postgresql

If I type `psql` directly in my command prompt, I am logged into postgres as the user `myusernamexy` with all rights I need.

However, I want to connect to the database with this command:

```
psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U myusernamexy mydatabasexy
```

When I type the above command into the command prompt, I get this error

```
FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "myusernamexy "
```

Why do I get this error and what do I need to change in the command to make it work?

Comment: because when you dont specify -h you connect to socket and go over local in pg_hba, when using -h you go over host line. if you want to change ident to password, change corresponding line to md5 or add it before other matching line

Comment: You definitely need to check your pg_hba.conf configuration https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html . Usually that is the first thing that needs a change in a fresh PostgreSQL instalation.